# Bokeh remove space between elements in gridplot

Tags: python, css, bokeh

I have a Bokeh app (`bokeh==1.0.1`) where I use gridplot to render a slider widgetbox and several figures. I am using `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`. How can I eliminate the white space between the widget row and the rest of the figure panels? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I create a layout for the widget as:

```
blank_button = bkm.widgets.RadioButtonGroup()
blank_wb = widgetbox(blank_button, width=50, height=100, sizing_mode='fixed') # placeholder for space
date_slider_wb = widgetbox(date_slider, width=400, height=100, sizing_mode='fixed')
apply_button = bkm.widgets.Button(label="APPLY")
apply_wb = widgetbox(apply_button, width=100, height=100, sizing_mode='fixed')

hor_layout_date_slider = (
    row(
      column(blank_wb),
      column(date_slider_wb),
      column(apply_wb),
    )
)
```

Then I include `hor_layout_date_slider` in a `gridplot` as:

```
grid = gridplot(
  children = [
    hor_layout_date_slider,
    airtemp_fig,
    windspeed_fig,
    winddir_fig,
    interval_fig,
    precip_fig,
    pressure_fig
    ],
    ncols=1,
    sizing_mode='stretch_both',
    merge_tools=False,
)

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

I am using the bokeh server and rendering the bokeh document in a single div in my html template as:

```
  <div class="placeholderbokehapp rounded" id="tbc-id">

<script src="http://localhost:5858/stormtracker_bokehapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1000&bokeh-app-path=/stormtracker_bokehapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5858/stormtracker_bokehapp&resources=none" id="1000"></script>
  </div>
```

As an attempted hack solution, I have been able to pass custom css rules to define the height of the div containing `hor_layout_date_slider`, but there is still a "place holder" for this element that persists (which I cannot access with inspect elements).

I have also tried using a simple widgetbox containing only the slider (without defining height and width and using `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`), instead of the full `hor_layout_date_slider` as defined above. However, this results in the same white space following the slider element.

Strangely enough, this problem does not occur with `sizing_mode='scale_width'` (the slider is tight in the layout).

Is there a Bokeh setting I am not aware of to control the spacing in this layout when using `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`?

**UPDATE:**

If I add the widget and the grid separately as:

```
curdoc().add_root(hor_layout_date_slider)
curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

The widget is then rendered underneath the first figure panel (you can see part of the slider widget showing through in the screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: The whitespace around the widgetbox is a result of all elements in the `gridplot()` forced to be the same height when using `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`. I have addressed this issue with a separate SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079873/bokeh-gridplot-define-different-heights-for-figures-with-sizing-mode-stretch-b

Comment: UPDATE: Using `sizing_mode='stretch_width'`, everything works great. Can put all elements (including the DateRangeSlider) in a `gridplot`, and then add a single object to the `curdoc()`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizing_mode` doesn't work well when nesting columns and rows in a grid or tabs. Just take the slider out of the grid and add separately to the root.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, RadioButtonGroup, Button

blank_button = RadioButtonGroup()
date_slider = Slider(start = 1, end = 10, value = 5)
apply_button = Button(label = "APPLY")

hor_layout_date_slider = row(blank_button, date_slider, apply_button)
airtemp_fig = figure()
windspeed_fig = figure()
grid = gridplot(children = [airtemp_fig, windspeed_fig],
                ncols = 1,
                sizing_mode = 'stretch_both',
                merge_tools = False)

curdoc().add_root(hor_layout_date_slider)
curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

Comment: see my update to the question with an additional screenshot. The slider widget is rendering behind the `grid`.

Comment: above example works for Bokeh v1.0.4. When using custom css (bokeh serve --show my_app_dir) think of that each widget element is normally put in a widgetbox even if not specified explicitly, so you need to apply custom css also to the container elements.

Comment: I upgraded to Bokeh v1.0.4 and still getting same behavior. However, the height of the slider widget div is now correct, so I can simply move the `grid` div down with some custom css. Not ideal, but will work.