# Bokeh gridplot: define different heights for figures with sizing_mode='stretch_both'

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to define different heights for individual figures in a Bokeh `gridplot` layout (`bokeh==1.0.4`)?

For example, I have three figures with three different heights:

```
p1 = figure(
     name="fig1",
     width=500, height=500,
)

p2 = figure(
     name="fig2",
     width=500, height=1000,
)

p1 = figure(
     name="fig3",
     width=500, height=100,
)
```

I then place the figures into a `gridplot` and add the root to `curdoc()`:

```
grid = gridplot(
  children = [p1,p2,p3],
  ncols=1,
  sizing_mode='stretch_both',
)

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

However, when I render the Bokeh document (using the Bokeh server), the height of each row is the same, scaled to fill the available space in the containing div.

If I use `sizing_mode='scale_width'` the figure heights are recognized and used. Why are the heights ignored for `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`?

Note that this behavior is the same if I use `layout()` instead of `gridplot()`.